# collection as association class?

Tags: uml

Does is make sense to have a collection as an association class? For example, if I want to represent that a Reader can read several Articles per day, does it make sense to represent it as:

> ```
>                                     * 
>                  Reader ------------- Date
>                              |
>                              |
>                         List<Article>
> ```

If it does, I would like to know how to represent that in UML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw something like this.

```
                  *
Reader ------------ Article
            |
            |
         ---------
         |Reading|
         ---------
         |Date   |
         ---------
```

Date is an attribute.